# how to get the values of list of radio buttons in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am a beginner to JSP. I am passing a list of images from a JAVA controller to JSP. In JSP I have created 2 radio buttons for each image in the list by iterating over the list. Now how will I get the radio button values for each image in JAVA controller.

My JAVA controller:

```
String[] imagesList = {"images/team.JPG", "images/team.JPG", "images/team.JPG", "images/team.JPG"};
model.addAttribute("imagesList",imagesList);
```

My Jsp:

```html
<c:forEach var="image" items="${imagesList}" varStatus="i">
    <input type="radio" name="${image}" value="${image}"/>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="${image}"  value="${image}"/>No    
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Am assuming you might have form and within that form you have this field?

Comment: Yes. It is within a form

Comment: Why are you using the same value for a group of `radio`? It won't make any change if user selects Yes or No, the same value will be sent to the server...

Comment: ${image} is every image in the ${imagesList}. So it is not the same value. The value for Yes/No radio buttons changes for each image. Right?

Comment: use same name for the radio button like radios and when you would submit the form, from jsp you could use request.getParameter("radios");?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can't possibly work with the HTML you created. Assume you have such a radio button in an HTML page:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="bar"/>
```

If the radio is unchecked, and the form is submitted, then no parameter at all will be sent.

If the radio is checked, and the form is submitted, then the parameter `foo=bar` will be sent.

So, in your case, you have

```
<input type="radio" name="${image}" value="${image}"/>Yes
<input type="radio" name="${image}"  value="${image}"/>No
```

This means that (assuming the image is "foo")

- if none of the radio is checked, no parameter will be sent for the image
- if "Yes" is checked, the parameter `foo=foo` will be sent
- if "No" is checked, the parameter `foo=foo` will be sent as well

So you have no way of telling the difference between Yes and No, since both checkboxes have the same value.

First, I wouldn't use an image path as name of the checkbox. Use an ID that uniquely identifies the image and doesn't contain characters that must be escaped like `/`.

Then use a different value for Yes and no:

```
<input type="radio" name="${image.id}" value="true"/>Yes
<input type="radio" name="${image.id}" value="false"/>No
```

Then you can iterate through all the request parameters and get all the ones whose value is true: their names are the IDs of the images for which Yes has been checked.

Note that it would be much more logical to use a unique checkbox per image, rather than 2 radio buttons:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkedImages" value="${image.id}"/>
```

By doing this, all you need to do is get the parameter values for the parameter named "checkedImages", and you will directly have an array containing all the IDs of the checked images.